# Non-zero coefficient in a transcendence proof

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

I am studying the proof of the simple version of Lindemann's Theorem.

**Theorem**.  If $\alpha$ is a non-zero algebraic number, then $e^\alpha$ is transcendental.

Apologies for the long read, but to explain my question I need to give a very brief summary of the first part of the proof.

Let $\alpha$ be algebraic with conjugates $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_l$.  Suppose $e^\alpha$ is algebraic with minimal polynomial
$$p(z)=c_0+c_1z+\cdots+c_mz^m$$
over the integers.  We expand
$$p(e^{\alpha_1})\cdots p(e^{\alpha_l})\tag{1}$$
as a sum
$$\sum_\beta a_\beta e^\beta\ ,$$
where each $\beta$ is an integer linear combination of the $\alpha_j$.  By collecting terms we obtain a similar sum in which all the $\beta$ are distinct.  Now it is clear that one of the $\beta$ values is zero, so that we have an integer term $c_0^l$.  However it is possible that more than one $\beta$ is zero, so after collecting terms we have something like
$$a_0+a_1e^{\beta_1}+\cdots\ ,\tag{2}$$
where the $\beta_j$ are non-zero.  If $a_0\ne0$ then the proof proceeds quite smoothly, but if $a_0=0$ then we have to modify the preceding expression... but I don't need to tell you about that.

**My question**: is this modification ever actually necessary?  That is, can $a_0$ ever be zero?  To be quite clear about it -

**Can anyone provide a specific example** of an algebraic number $\alpha$ and an irreducible polynomial $p$ such that when we expand $(1)$ we obtain an expression like $(2)$ with $a_0=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible example (some details to work out): Let $p(z)=144z^5-27z^3-110z^2-84z-133$ which I expect to be irreducible over the rationals (should be a simple check left to the OP) and let $\alpha_1,..\alpha_5$ the roots.

Then since the sum of the roots is zero (and again I expect no other integral linear relation between them though it is something to be checked), when one does $p(e^{\alpha_1})\cdots p(e^{\alpha_5})$, one gets a free term which is $144^5-27^5-110^5-84^5-133^5=0$ per the famous [Lander and Parkin counterexample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_power_(algebra)) to Euler's conjecture

Comment: Thanks for that @conrad!  First comment: I am stunned!!  Would you care to share the ideas that led you to this example?  Did you start with Lander/Parkin?  Surely you must have - but even then, why????

Comment: Second comment: I am perhaps not totally sure, but very confident that your answer is correct.  I didn't bother checking irreducibility of $p$ myself, but asked Maple, which is good enough for me.  (Shouldn't be too hard though - only need to check rational roots and quadratic times cubic.)  I couldn't see how to check "properly" that there are no unexpected linear relations, but did floating point calculations of linear combinations, and nothing comes out anywhere near zero except the ones we want.

Comment: I thought of the simplest example where the sum of the roots is zero (that gives easy extra constant terms in our product) then it follows degree odd and sadly for $3$ you would need a non trivial fermat cubic triple of which there are none, but for $5$ you need $4$ fifth powers to add to a fifth such and that reminded me of those numbers; as for linear relations I think a proof is doable by contradiction  as another one would mean two roots are expressed in terms of three others (using sum zero) and some norm manipulation may work - it would be really shocking to have such

Comment: Thanks for the extra comment - actually I was just beginning to realise that for myself :)    We specify that the sum of roots of $p$ is to be zero as an easy way of getting extra integer terms.  Then, assuming no other relations, the integer term is$$c_m^l+c_{m-1}^l+\cdots+c_1^l+c_0^l\ .$$Since $c_{m-1}=0$ this means that we want a sum of $m$ $l$th powers to vanish.  Not sure if you noticed that $m$ and $l$ may be different, so perhaps there is a simpler example.  Will keep thinking about this.

Comment: Another important thing - I want this example for a book I expect to publish later this year, and I would be more than happy to give you an acknowledgement.  Can do that via your MSE login (and give a reference to this answer), but perhaps you would rather have your full name used?  Maybe we can have a private chat about this?

Comment: it's fine to use the MSE login (or even just credit an MSE answer without attribution) no problem; I think it is $m$ powers (as you need the product of all $e^{\alpha_k}$) but the coefficients except $c_m, c_0$ may also vanish (actually you need at least $3$ non zero coefficients) and the power must be odd and at least $3$ and higher or equal to the number of the coefficients, so $m \ge 5$; now, of course, you can try two fifth powers adding to two other fifth powers or to three such and I am sure you will get other examples

Comment: Here $l$ is the degree of the given $\alpha$ while $m$ is the (hypothetical, looking for a contradiction) degree of $e^\alpha$.  So I'm fairly sure I don't need them to be equal.  And I haven't finished checking, but I think another example is given by $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{2}$ and (using a cubic relation even more famous than Lander/Parkin!)$$p(z)=12z^4+z^2-10z-9\ .$$

Comment: yes you are right of course - so I agree that there may be simpler examples